# set vertical position of expand icon for expandablelistview

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I'm trying to edit the position of the expand icon in the expandable listview. I set it's horizontal position using the following code which I found on another discussion but dont see a method to change it's vertical position...

```
Display newDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = newDisplay.getWidth();
newListView.setIndicatorBounds(width-50, width);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just define a custom layout for the header row? then you can put the expand icon wherever you want and you don't have to mess with the complicated code.

Comment: You're probably right, quite new to android and couldn't find anything in the expandable listview methods so was just asking to see if anything quick and easy was available to do what I want...

Comment: look at the [SimpleExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) if you just need to display simple stuff. for more complicated displaying, you will need to create a custom adapter to handle your views.